# Azure Search suggestions issue

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am using .net sdk for azure search. I am facing one issue related to suggestion, customer name and contact name where I have applied suggestions.

When I type text like "Ed Mar" then it gives suggestion "Ed Mark Consulting" and skips "Ed Mark."

In short when customer and contact name are nearly same, then it suggest only customer name.

Is it something related to scoring preference?

Modified question:

Hi Bruce,

This is my code

```
SuggestParameters sp = new SuggestParameters()
{
    UseFuzzyMatching = fuzzy,
    Top = 8,
    MinimumCoverage =100,                   
};   

return indexClient.Documents.Suggest(searchText, "Suggester", sp);
```

Where searchText is for eg : "Ed Mar"

I have a index called "customer" under that customer I have applied suggester to "customerName" and "contactName"
So we have documents with customerName :"Ed Mark Consulting" and contactName : "Ed Mark" so when I type "Ed Mar" the document returned only for
customerName and not for Contact Name i.e: "Ed Mark Consulting" is displayed as suggestion and not "Ed Mark" this is issue only where customer and contact name
are nearly same else it works fine individually for customer and contact name.

Comment: The Suggest operation in Azure Search returns documents, not individual fields. It sounds like you're describing what you're seeing in a UI, not what Azure Search is returning to you. Can you clarify what exactly Azure Search is returning to you, as well as the code you're using to call Suggest in the SDK? Thanks.

Comment: Bruce, I have edited my question, since comments not allowing to have long text, please check.

Answer (score 0):

The Suggest operation in Azure Search returns *document suggestions*; the response contains a matched sequence of terms from a single field for each *suggested document* even if there are matches in multiple fields in that document. This behavior is expected.

Also, to answer your question, Suggest operations cannot use custom scoring profile, only Search operation can.

It'd be more helpful if you could describe what you are trying to accomplish with the Suggest API. Based on your description, in order to retrieve matches from all fields, the Search API with highlight may be more suitable in your scenario.

Hope this helps.

Nate